# How to make a triangle with for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm following an online course that should make me learn computer scienze( basics )with python.
I'm studying 'for loop' and it seems very simple, in teory.
I can't make works thi code, below:

```
n=int( input() )
for i in range( 0, 1 ) :
   X = 0
   for j in range( n, 0 ) : 
       X = ( X * 10 ) + 1
       print( X )
```

The output should be:

```
111
11
1
```

But, when I run it, i get thi error:

```
 "Did not pass tests. Please check details below and try again.
Results for test case 1 out of 2
Input:
3
Program executed without crashing.

Program output:
0
Expected this correct output:
```

111
11
1

```
Result of grading: Your output is not correct.
```

If I try to change ( n, 0 ), I will get thi outuput:

```
1
11
111
```

Can someone help me, please?

I've done it!

Comment: Don't you mean ```range(n)``` instead of ```range(n,0)```? Now it iterates from ```n``` till ```0```, so if ```n```>=0 it will not iterate at all.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

```py
for i in range(n):
     print('1' * (n - i))
```

Comment: The output is: 11 / 11 / 11

Comment: For n = 3, the range function should return a generator that gives you [0, 1, 2], so n - i should gives you [3, 2, 1]. So I cannot see how you get three '11' output.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `for j in range( n, 0 ) :` runs 0 times, since n is already greater than 0.

Try `for j in range( n, 0 ,-1) :`.

The third argument -1 represents the step between the first and second iterators.

Implying now it decrements by 1 for every iteration.

This would be the solution, you are looking for.

```
n = int(input())

for i in range(0,n):
    for _ in range(0, n-i):
        print('1',end = '')
    print()
```

Comment: The output is : -11- -11- -11-

Comment: Are you taking inputs dynamically?

Comment: The program give me the input 3.

Comment: It works and gives me the output that you wanted. I've edited it, to make input dynamic. Try it now.